# Openlayers 4: WFS Format always flips coordinates on EPSG:4326

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

When using the `ol.format.WFS` (both GML2 and GML3) to read features they will always be assumed to be in YX if the projection is EPSG:4326. So OL flips them. I am using this with Geoserver 2.11 and, as of this version, the server can send the coordinates as XY, depending on how you pass the projection. You can read about it [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/basics.html#axis-ordering).

Going through the OL code I can see it reads the projection from the xml and it decides to flip it based on the axis orientation, which for 4326 is neu, resulting in a flip.

The problem is my configuration depends on the client and the server might be already sending XY. I was wondering if this is a bug with OpenLayers or if it was a decision made.

Is there a way to prevent it from doing it?

Answer (score 2):

You can override it with a custom projection object

```
/ override the axis orientation for WMS GetFeatureInfo
var proj = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: 'http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326',
  axis: 'enu'
});
ol.proj.addEquivalentProjections([ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326'), proj]);
```

Just make sure that the string for code matches what is in your WFS/GML document.

Comment: I am not 100% sure that that solution is viable for me. The web client I am building has the possibility of serving different services, which could be in different servers. That means the configuration could change based on the layer/service being shown. That could mean constantly changing the definition of the projection for each query. I was thinking as maybe a more viable solution maybe overwriting the function that does the check.